# What are the images under $f$ of lines parallel to the coordinate axes?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f=(f_1,f_2)$ be the mapping of $\mathbb{R^2}$ into $\mathbb{R^2}$ given by $$ f_1(x,y)=e^x \cos y,\quad f_2(x,y)=e^x \sin y.$$ What are the images under $f$ of lines parallel to the coordinate axes?

My Try:

A line parallel to $y-$axis is of the form $x=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Then, $f(c,y)=(e^c \cos y, e^c \sin y)$. Let $u=e^c \cos y$ and $v=e^c \sin y$.

Then $u^2+v^2=e^{2c}$. Hence, the image is a circle centered at the origin and of radius $e^c$.

A line parallel to $x-$axis is of the form $y=c$ where $c$ is a constant. Then, $f(x,c)=(e^x \cos c,e^x \sin c)$. Let $u=e^x \cos c$ and $v=e^x \sin c$. Now how can I proceed like in the previous case? Can somebody please help me to find the image curve?

Answer (score 0):

The image curve is the line starting at the origin of slope $\frac{\sin(c)}{\cos(c)} = \tan(c)$. This is because the mapping $x \mapsto e^x (\cos(c), \sin(c))$ has as image the positive real multiples of the vector $\mathbf{v} = (\cos(c), \sin(c))$.